# Add posts from a category to menu with all posts in it as sub menu

Tags: menus

Because there is no category option on pages I desided to add post category to main nav.
I added the category and added posts on it but it doesn't dsplays the sub category on menu.
what should I do to make it work?

Another thing is If I am inside one of the post/page of a category I want to display all the page / post menu on left side bar.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I had put the following code into sidebar.php to display a list eith sub-categories  of "Store" categori and the posts of them. 
Hope I understand what you need and it will be helpfull. if not can ask more explicite

```
            <?
                // Get categories for parent category store
                // Get ID cat by slug
                $id_store = get_category_id('store');

                $stores = get_categories(array('child_of' => $id_store, 'hide_empty' => 0));
            ?>
                <ul>
                     <?php foreach ($stores as $categ_list): ?>
                        <li class="cats-<?php echo $categ_list->cat_ID; ?> dropcats">

                                <?php echo $categ_list->cat_name; ?>


            <?php       
                    $args = array(
                        'category' => $categ_list->cat_ID,
                        'numberposts' => -1,
                        'orderby' => 'title',
                        'order' => 'asc'
                    );

                    // Get posts for store category

                    $store_posts = get_posts($args);
                    // If there is any posts
                    if (count($store_posts) > 0) {
            ?>

                            <ul class="markes">
                                <?php foreach ($store_posts as $post) { ?>              
                                    <li class="post-<?php echo $post->ID; ?>">
                                        <a href="<?php echo $post->post_name; ?>" class="marke-<?php echo $post->ID;?>">
                                            <?php echo $post->post_name; ?> 
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                <?php } ?>
                                 </li>
                            </ul>

            <?php   } 

                endforeach;
            ?>
            </ul>

        </aside>
```

Comment: I added a plugin called "Sub Pages widget". it worked for me. Here is the [link](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/subpages-widget/)